# Just confused on how binding works in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've finished creating a CRUD in angularjs it just got me wondering why when i change the value of vm.userlistData2 it also changes the vm.userlistData that was being displayed..

here's how i get the data using a service

```
 dataservice.getUserProfile(vm.userId).then(function (data) {
  vm.userlistData = data;
  vm.userlistData2 = data;
});
```

Comment: Because both are just a reference to the same `data` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because userlistData  and userlistData2 share the same object reference. you can use object.assign to avoid this by creating a new object reference for userlistData2 :

```js
vm.userlistData = data;
vm.userlistData2 = Object.assign({}, data);
```

Advance data structure and JS Hint recommends you angular.copy
Usage: 
angular.copy(source, [destination]);

Your example : 
  angular.copy(data,vm.userlistData);
  angular.copy(data,vm.userlistData2);

- angular automates the memory management so no need to worry about creating a new reference .

Comment: Also try `angular.copy(data)`

Comment: Yes, Object.assign doesn't work with array. angular.copy does